# Is there better way to simulate standard input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I just write one bash script this afternoon. It's quite ugly. So i think there must exists better way to implement `echo $x` here.

```
for x in $(ls); do 
    cp $x $(echo $x | sed s/\\./_holo_light./) 
    cp $x $(echo $x | sed s/\\./_holo_dark./) 
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
for x in *; do 
    cp "$x" "${x/./_holo_light.}"
    cp "$x" "${x/./_holo_dark.}"
done
```

- [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use a glob instead.
- You don't need `sed` here. Bash can perform [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).
- [Quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) your variables.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
ls | sed 's/a/c/g'
```

Comment: I updated my question. I not only need to print the files, but rename several files.

Comment: @hongbosb don't ask one question then edit it to asked a different question! See dogbane's answers to the question you actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Note that parsing output from ls has [some issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), if you are sure you're not affected, you could do it like this (GNU sed):

```
ls | 
sed -nr 's/(.*)\.(.*)$/cp "\1.\2" "\1_holo_light.\2"\ncp "\1.\2" "\1_halo_dark.\2"/p' |
sh
```

Where sed generates the copy commands which are then passed on the a shell to execute. Review the output of sed before you append `| sh`.

Comment: +1 If you add quotes to the filenames, using ls should be no problem.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Yes I agree that would alleviate some of the issues, added and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While the answers mentioned here are correct & optimized,
for your original question text, "simulate standard input", you can use here string.

```
echo "$var" | command
```

can be replaced with

```
command <<< "$var"
```

Comment: That feature is called a "here string", not a variable substitution.